# How to create documentation linked with GitHub?

Tags: github, github-pages

I was just reading this [elasticsearch link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html). I found edit option with every heading which was redirecting me to GitHub website. I know git provides wiki option with every account but that is hosted on GitHub only and supports limited features.

How can I make documentation like this that is linked to GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they're using [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) and just put the repository on Github.

The edit links don't appear to be a special feature of AsciiDoc. They're simple URLs of the form `https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>/edit/5.x/<path>`. Presumably someone regenerates the site after they accept a pull request.

This will work with most site generation tools, it doesn't appear to be anything specific to AsciiDoc.

Answer (score 0):

I read:

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest-getting-started.html
```

Then I want edit, it redirect to:

```
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/edit/5.x/docs/client-concepts/high-level/getting-started.asciidoc
```

Link source code:

```
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/docs/client-concepts/high-level/getting-started.asciidoc
```

URL file:

```
elasticsearch-net/docs/client-concepts/high-level/getting-started.asciidoc
```

The different is URL parameter: `edit` and `blob`. How to create documentation linked with GitHub? So simple, use this convention when create static document file.